# How to subtract number of strings in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, split

It would be great if you can share some help for my problem. Basically my dataset is a bit different. It looks like the following.

```
            1                  2
1   [34, 67], [17, 76]       [17, 76], , , , , ,
```

I would like to get rid of the "[", "]" and extra ","s, and make a vector of numbers.

Ideally it should look like the following

```
            1               2
1   "[34, 67]", "[17, 76]"     "[17, 76]"
```

or

```
          1               2
1   "34, 67", "17, 76"     "17, 76"
```

I try the following

```
a=trimws(df[1,1])
a=unlist(strsplit(a, split=", "))
```

but it returns with "[34" "67]" "[17" "76]". Are there any easy ways to achieve this?

This is a sample of what I get from dput():

```
structure(list(rse1e = structure(c(3L, 7L), .Label = c("", ", , , , , , ", 
"[118, 25], [17, 76], [56, 56], [34, 67], , , ", "[17, 76], , , , , , ", 
"[34, 67], [118, 25], [17, 76], [0, 84], [84, 42], [56, 56], [151, 8]", 
"[34, 67], [168, 0], , , , , ", "[56, 56], [0, 84], [34, 67], [168, 0], [151, 8], , ", 
"[56, 56], [118, 25], [0, 84], , , , ", "{\"ImportId\":\"rse1e\"}", 
"rse1e"), class = "factor"), rse2e = structure(6:7, .Label = c("", 
", , , , , , , ", "[0, 54], [173, 11], [22, 49], [108, 27], [86, 32], [43, 43], [130, 22], [216, 0]", 
"[108, 27], [0, 54], , , , , , ", "[151, 16], [216, 0], [108, 27], , , , , ", 
"[22, 49], [108, 27], [86, 32], [151, 16], , , , ", "[43, 43], [108, 27], [173, 11], [130, 22], [0, 54], , , ", 
"[86, 32], , , , , , , ", "{\"ImportId\":\"rse2e\"}", "rse2e"
), class = "factor")), row.names = 15:16, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you `dput()` your data? here is a case when we'll need to know carefully what exactly is in your data

Comment: @MichaelChirico, sorry for the confusion, I try to dput() the data in the question. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what your data looks like but removing the brackets and splitting by `|` can be achieved like this:

```
f <- "1 [34, 67], [17, 76] | [17, 76]"
[1] "1 [34, 67], [17, 76] | [17, 76]"
# remove the brackets
gsub("\\[|\\]", "", f)
[1] "1 34, 67, 17, 76 | 17, 76"
# split by |, we need unlist here since strsplit() returns a list
unlist(strsplit(a, "(?<=[|])", perl = TRUE))
[1] "1 34, 67, 17, 76 |" " 17, 76"
```

If you do not want to keep `|` as your delimiter then you can do:

```
unlist(strsplit(a, "[|]", perl = TRUE))
[1] "1 34, 67, 17, 76 " " 17, 76"
```

Comment: oh sorry, "|" is not in the data file! I put it here to indicate that they are two separate columns..

Comment: Sorry again, I think the way that I ask the question is bad. I try gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Data), but it is returning me with values, would it be possible to convert it to a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df[]<-trimws(gsub("\\[|\\]|,","",as.matrix(df)))
```

such that

```
> df
                          rse1e                           rse2e
15     118 25 17 76 56 56 34 67       22 49 108 27 86 32 151 16
16 56 56 0 84 34 67 168 0 151 8 43 43 108 27 173 11 130 22 0 54
```

**EDIT**:
To split the string in terms of bracket

```
s <- "[34, 67], [118, 25], [17, 76], [0, 84], [84, 42], [56, 56], [151, 8]"
> unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]",s)))
[1] "[34, 67]"  "[118, 25]" "[17, 76]"  "[0, 84]"   "[84, 42]"  "[56, 56]"  "[151, 8]"
```

Comment: would it be possible to have the numbers stores as a vecter? like "118", "25", "17", "76", "56", "56", "34", "67"  instead of a long string "118 25 17 76 56 56 34 67 "

Comment: @RuiGuan yes, it is possible, but in that case how do you want to store the numbers in your data frame?

Comment: Thank, I have just updated the post. Actually it is better for the followup coding if "[34, 67], [17, 76]"  can be turned into "[34, 67]", "[17, 76]"  or "34, 67", "17, 76", is that possible?

Comment: ideally they can be stored as a string in the frame

Comment: @RuiGuan I added one more line to show you how to split the string, but I have no picture in my mind how to put the string vector in your data frame as the output

Answer (score 0):

We can also remove all characters which are not numbers with a space.

```
df[] <- trimws(gsub('\\D', ' ', unlist(df)))
```

To get output in different columns, we can use `cSplit`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, names(df), sep = " ")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, by the way, it is possible to even split the entries into columns such that every column has only one number?